# How do I remove Steam Inbox mail?

Tags: steam

Near the top of the Steam, there is a green box with an image of a letter. Is there a way to remove all of the notifications at once? Without paying attention, I ended up getting over 300 of them, and I want to remove all of the notifications.

Comment: I've found that generally clicking on each of the sub-categories (ie, chat messages, gifts, etc) tends to clear them.  I've never had that many, though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If those notifications are comments, you can go to the new comment overview and click "Mark all Read", there is a small link for this at the top, if you have unread comments.

[image: SCreenshot of Steam feature]

As for inventory  and the other categories, you have to go to your inventory and dismiss the new items notification or read any unread chat messages seperately or accept your 300 Gifts. There is no way doing this all at once currently.